# When using gnu make with -C option, how can I find the original calling directory?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to determine the directory from which the user called make when they use the '-C' command line option?

UPDATE:
A bit more explanation. I know in theory I should not need it. However in my case the user of the Makefiles would like to be able to control where the binaries end up, so I have allowed them to give me the path where they want them. So they can do something like:

```
make OUTPUT_PATH=/home/user/build/
```

However that breaks down when they call make from the directory they want to use for output.

```
cd /home/user/build
make -C /home/user/source OUTPUT_PATH=.
```

Hope that makes it a bit more clear. I am inclined to say this is not possible, but I wanted to query the community at large.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU make itself does not provide this ability.  However, many shells will set the `PWD` environment variable, and since GNU make imports all environment variables as make macros, you can find out this way:

```
$ pwd
/home/madscientist

$ echo 'all: ; @echo $(PWD) $(CURDIR)' | make -f-
/home/madscientist /home/madscientist

$ echo 'all: ; @echo $(PWD) $(CURDIR)' | make -f- -C /tmp
/home/madscientist /tmp
```

Be aware, this relies on the shell's behavior!  Different users' shells may behave differently.